# I am trying to give animation to my image that I am using as a background using CSS but the keyframes do not seem to work

Tags: css, animation

```css
    .img.wrapper img{
    
            width: 200%;
            height: 200%;
            position: relative;
            object-fit: cover;
            opacity: 0.5;
            animation-name: scale;
            animation-duration: 25s; 
    }
    
    @keyframes scale { 
      0%{
        
          transform: scale(1.3);
        }  
      100%{
        
          transform: scale(1);
        }
    }
```

This is the styling i have given to the image and the animation name is scale transform doesn't seem to work why?

Comment: are you aware that 25s is a big value for duration? you need to wait all that time to see a small scale

Comment: It works to me with the snippet you provided, assuming the HTML is correct: `<div class="img wrapper">
  <img src="https://cdn.trendhunterstatic.com/thumbs/cool-backgrounds.jpeg" />
</div>`